# When I convert HTML files to Adobe Air, how I can add CSS and Images?

Tags: air, adobe

If you convert HTML files to Adobe Air files, please let me know how you can add css and image files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tutorial: [Adobe AIR Tutorial for HTML / JavaScript Developers](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/667.cfm)

Specifically:

> If you want to add CSS, JavaScript, or
>   images, you can create subfolders in
>   your /appname/source/ folder for those
>   assets, and use them just like you
>   would in a normal web application.